# Go cannot find package

Tags: go

I'm trying to checkout this Go project https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-model and build according to the readme:

```
> mkdir -p "$HOME/Go/src/github.com/fabric8io"
> export GOPATH="$HOME/Go"
> cd "$HOME/Go/src/github.com/fabric8io"
> git clone https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-model
> cd kubernetes-model
> brew install go
> brew install godep
> make
CGO_ENABLED=0 GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1 go build -a ./cmd/generate/generate.go
cmd/generate/generate.go:27:2: cannot find package "github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/authorization/api/v1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/authorization/api/v1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/authorization/api/v1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:28:2: cannot find package "github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/build/api/v1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/build/api/v1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/build/api/v1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:29:2: cannot find package "github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/deploy/api/v1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/deploy/api/v1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/deploy/api/v1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:30:2: cannot find package "github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/image/api/v1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/image/api/v1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/image/api/v1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:31:2: cannot find package "github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/oauth/api/v1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/oauth/api/v1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/oauth/api/v1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:32:2: cannot find package "github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/project/api/v1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/project/api/v1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/project/api/v1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:33:2: cannot find package "github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/route/api/v1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/route/api/v1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/route/api/v1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:34:2: cannot find package "github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/template/api/v1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/template/api/v1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/template/api/v1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:35:2: cannot find package "github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/user/api/v1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/user/api/v1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/user/api/v1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:36:2: cannot find package "k8s.io/apiextensions-server/pkg/apis/apiextensions/v1beta1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/k8s.io/apiextensions-server/pkg/apis/apiextensions/v1beta1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/k8s.io/apiextensions-server/pkg/apis/apiextensions/v1beta1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:37:2: cannot find package "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/resource" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/resource (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/resource (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:38:2: cannot find package "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/unversioned" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/unversioned (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/unversioned (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:39:2: cannot find package "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/v1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/v1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/v1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:40:2: cannot find package "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/apps/v1beta1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/apps/v1beta1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/apps/v1beta1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:41:2: cannot find package "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/autoscaling/v1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/autoscaling/v1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/autoscaling/v1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:43:2: cannot find package "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/batch/v1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/batch/v1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/batch/v1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:42:2: cannot find package "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/batch/v2alpha1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/batch/v2alpha1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/batch/v2alpha1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:44:2: cannot find package "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/extensions/v1beta1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/extensions/v1beta1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/extensions/v1beta1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:45:2: cannot find package "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/unversioned/clientcmd/api/v1" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/unversioned/clientcmd/api/v1 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/unversioned/clientcmd/api/v1 (from $GOPATH)
cmd/generate/generate.go:46:2: cannot find package "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/watch/json" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/watch/json (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/watch/json (from $GOPATH)
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

I'm not sur what I'm supposed to do with this as I'm used to build tools that download automatically dependencies.

EDIT: I also tried:

```
> make update-deps
make: *** No rule to make target `update-deps'.  Stop.
> make [tag=v0.5.2] update-deps
make: *** No rule to make target `update-deps'.  Stop.
> make tag=v0.5.2 update-deps
make: *** No rule to make target `update-deps'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Some of that projects documentation seems to be broken, but have you tried running `make update-deps` as shown in the README?

Comment: All those dependencies are vendored. Are you certain you're working in your GOPATH?

Answer (score 0):

You should clone repository and set proper GOPATH for it.
The folders structure must be:

```
kubernetes-model
                \ src
                     \github.com
                                \fabric8io
                                          \kubernetes-model
                                                           \ <project files here>

export GOPATH=<location of first 'kubernetes-model' folder in this chain>
```

This export will make `vendor` directory of project visible for `go`

Comment: This is what I did except that I named the first `kubernetes-model`, `Go`. Is it important? I just edited the question with the exact steps I've done.

Comment: No, it is not important. But I see in your log next path: `/Users/joangoyeau/Code/go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/authorization/api/v1 (from $GOPATH)` where `go` directory is lower-cased, but in your `export GOPATH="$HOME/Go"` it is camel-cased.